# Antec 900 fan plugs are not compatible with PSU or motherboard

Tags: power-supply, fan, adapter, molex

I have an Antec 900 case, which has two small fans in the front, a large fan on top, and an exhaust fan in the back, all of which have individual power cords/plugs. They look identical to the piece on the left in [this picture.](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&sa=N&tbm=isch&tbnid=-sQZcChSW9GRNM:&imgrefurl=http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/245682-28-controller-antec-case&docid=g_ub63LMI-5IMM&imgurl=http://www.maplin.co.uk/images/Full/a01bf.jpg&w=1024&h=1024&ei=kKbsT_y7KpOs8ATW3rXkBQ&zoom=1&biw=939&bih=595) I have been told it plugs directly into the power supply, but I have no plugs that connect with this- I do have a female cord similar to this, but no males. There is 1 slot on my motherboard that will accept this plug, but there are 4 fans, so I'm in a fix... any help? Do I need an adapter that will let me connect to the molex connectors from the PSU? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually that connecter goes into the mother board, that provides power and allows software to report the fan speed:

[image]

But if your motherboard doesn't contain any connectors for your fans, you will need an adapter:

[image]

**e.g.,**

They can be found at amazon:

- [Link Depot 3-Pin Female to 4-Pin Male PC Power Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JWXGY6)
- [Cables Unlimited 3-Pin ATX Fan to 4-Pin Molex Connector Cable FAN-CABLE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V6T5HW)
- [Zalman ZM-MC1 Multi-connector PS to Add Fan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FAKUE6)